# Google Add-on publishing error: Cannot set private visibility using an account with no customer ID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

My Google Sheets add-on was rejected but I really only want to use it internally. I should be able to publish it privately, but I keep getting this error and I don't know what it means or how to fix.

App Visibility: "Cannot set private visibility using an account with no customer ID"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message could be related to the add on being selected as public when it was created. This [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview#determine_your_audience) explains this behavior. An option would be to create a new project and set it as private.

Edit:

The error message is showing up as the account used was under the gmail.com domain and the documentation states that setting it as private will allow it to be accessed by users under that account, [@Grace Ratley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17854248/grace-ratley) was able to get around it by using a Google Workspace account instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Yeah, when you enter visibility for the first time it can't be changed (which is super inconvenient). So I had to create a new project to begin with when my first was rejected. But I still have this error

Comment: Are you using a Google Workspace account? Checking the documentation again it seems that the option to set it up "private" Is to set it to a specific domain. If it's a regular gmail.com account the option shouldn't be available as any personal account would have access to it being within the same domain and as it's required to perform verification for certain add ons.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. I'll switch over to my company admin account. Thanks!